# What is DataProcSparkOperator?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

What is, esentially, DataProcSparkOperator? I found lots of information and pieces of code using it, however, I still cannot find a solid definition for it.

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not see this comment before! It did help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataproc is a managed Apache Spark and Apache Hadoop service that lets you take advantage of open source data tools for batch processing, querying, streaming, and machine learning. Dataproc automation helps you create clusters quickly, manage them easily, and save money by turning clusters off when you don't need them. You can see more in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference).

You can see more documentation about different DataProc operators [here](http://Https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/dataproc.html#google-cloud-dataproc-operators).

Airflow provides DataProcSparkOperator to submit the jobs to your dataproc cluster.

Here is the example:

```
submit_job = DataProcSparkOperator(
task_id='submit_job',
dataproc_spark_jars=['{{var.value.spark_bq_jar}}'],
main_class='LoadData',
arguments=[
"job_name==currency",
"data_type=={{params.thirty_raw_folder_prefix}}",
"input_path==gs://input-bucket/input-folder",
"output_path==gs://staging-bucket/staging_folder",
"week=={{dag_run.conf['week']}}",
"year=={{dag_run.conf['year']}}",
"genres=={{dag_run.conf['genres']}}"
],
files=['gs://bucket/folder/properties/loaddata.properties'],
cluster_name='{{params.cluster_name}}',
dag=dag
)
```

Here, the spark_bq_jar variable contains the location of your spark jar. And all the arguments are provided to tell the jar which job to run.
You can see more examples in this [link](https://medium.com/@jd_v/using-dataproc-for-spark-jobs-55eda272246d).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are talking about is the Apache Airflow operator for submitting Spark job to Dataproc cluster. Check the [Airflow doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcSparkSqlOperator), this [introductory article](https://medium.com/@jd_v/using-dataproc-for-spark-jobs-55eda272246d), this [example code](https://gist.github.com/yudetamago/7d653518ca20b3f96bc7ef56059e34d7).